# fork() and exit() in C

Tags: c, fork, wait, exit

I am trying to understand the following, where only child process is creating children.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    int n;
    int num_kids;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: forkloop <numkids>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    num_kids = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (i = 0; i < num_kids; i++) {
        n = fork();
        if (n > 0) {
            printf("pid = %d, ppid = %d, i = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), i);
            if (wait(NULL) == -1) {
                perror("wait");
            }
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("pid = %d, ppid = %d, i = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I right in understanding that, at the end of every loop, the parent process exits, and the child becomes the new parent? The reason is the exit() statement, which terminates the parent process? Also, does wait() in the parent, wait for its child to terminate, every iteration of the loop and only then exit? But, then the child never really exits, so when does the wait statement come into play?

Comment: Suggest you run the program and see what happens. Add some more `printf` statements if that helps you. That's the best way to understand it. But yes, `wait` does wait for the child to exit. The last created child will not call `fork` due to the `for` loop reaching the end. So it will exit by reaching the end of `main` and then its parent will exit and so on up the chain.

Comment: You currently have the parent waiting for its first child to die and then exiting, while the child goes on to execute the next iteration of the loop (as if it was the parent).  So yes, the your description of what is happening is mostly correct, except the children do die.  The main issue is that the parent doesn't exit immediately — all its progeny (its children's children's children, etc)  have to die.  You could improve the trackability by reporting on the process that is exiting immediately before the `return 0;` in `main()`.  It would be good to print the child PID in the parent code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right in understanding that, at the end of every loop, the parent
>   process exits, and the child becomes the new parent? The reason is the
>   exit() statement, which terminates the parent process?

Yes, but the process doesn't die immediately. Each "parent" calls `wait()` and waits for the child process to complete.

> Also, does wait() in the parent, wait for its child to terminate,
>   every iteration of the loop and only then exit?

Yes. That means the "parent" processes die in the reverse order. That means the very first process dies last.

> But, then the child never really exits, so when does the wait
>   statement come into play?

All processes die in your code. When the first child continues to execute the `for` loop, the parent process waits (and similarly all other child processes wait for their child processes). The very last process dies by going out of the loop and exits via `main()` returning.